# ArgumentException: The Assembly Microsoft.Msagl is referenced by BayesServer.Layout

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bayesian, bayesian-networks

I need help with implementing the bayes network in Unity. I downloaded the [bayes server](https://www.bayesserver.com/) developer API from [here](https://www.bayesserver.com/downloadlinks.aspx?major=8&minor=3&revision=0&build=0) as zip and extracted it in my Unity assets folder. When I try to build the game, I get the following error. Could you please help me with this error?

> ArgumentException: The Assembly Microsoft.Msagl is referenced by
>   BayesServer.Layout
>   ('Assets/bayesserver-8.3/DotNet/Standard20/BayesServer.Layout.dll').
>   But the dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found.
>   UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.AddReferencedAssembliesRecurse
>   (System.String assemblyPath, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T]
>   alreadyFoundAssemblies, System.String[] allAssemblyPaths,
>   System.String[] foldersToSearch,
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] cache,
>   UnityEditor.BuildTarget target) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:154)
>   UnityEditor.AssemblyHelper.FindAssembliesReferencedBy (System.String[]
>   paths, System.String[] foldersToSearch, UnityEditor.BuildTarget
>   target) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssemblyHelper.cs:194)
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Below is where I added the bayesserver library folder.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the two dll files shown in the screenshot below fixed the issue.
[image]